# Probability of getting two black balls

Tags: probability

Suppose a box contains 5 white balls and 5 black balls.

If you want to extract a ball and then another:

What is the probability of getting a black ball and then a black one?

I think that this is the answer:

Let $A:$ get a black ball in the first extraction, $B:$ get a black ball in the second extraction. Then: $P(A)=\frac{5}{10}$ and
$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{\frac{4}{9}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{8}{9}$$

Is this correct?

Now, If you want to extract two balls at the same time: 
what is the probability that both are black? 
Is exactly the same probability of the first question? 
Why?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Regarding the first question, is the first ball replaced after extraction or not?

Comment: By symmetry, you expect the answer to be the same if you replace "black" by "white". Do you see a problem with 8/9 being the answer then?

Comment: @wnvl No, the ball is not replaced.

Comment: According to the text, what you want to calculate is the probability of getting two black balls if you draw two balls one after the other ("a black one and then a black one"). According to your used formula and notation, what you want to calculate is the probability that the second drawn ball is black *if* the first one was black. So which one do you actually want to calculate?

Comment: @mrf No, I don't think so, because the answer is too "big".

Comment: @celtschk excuse my English. Yes, I want to calculate the probability of getting two black balls "a black one and then a black one". According to Cameron, my answer is obviously wrong, but why my notation is wrong? $P(B|A)$ denotes the probability of getting a black ball if already obtained a black ball.. Thanks

Comment: The probability of getting forst $A$ and then $B$ is *not* the same as the probability of getting $B$ if you already got $A$. For example, the probability that your next two coin tosses give head is $1/4$, but the probability to get a head if you just got a head is $1/2$. The first one is the combined probability of both events, while for the other one you assume the first event *already happened* (so it no longer is described by a probability: you *know* it happened), and asks what *now* is the probability to get the other result.

Comment: To add a possibly more illustrative example: Assume I tell you a random digit, and then the same digit again. The probability that I'll tell you the digit "3" followed by the digit "3" is $1/10$ (because I've got 10 digits to choose from), but the probability that I tell you a "3" as second digit if I told a "3" as first is $1$ (because that's the rule of the game).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is good to check an answer for plausibility. **Given** that the first ball is black, surely the probability that the second ball is black cannot be $\dfrac{8}{9}$!

In this case, it is the **conditional probability** that is obvious. Note that $\Pr(B|A)=\dfrac{4}{9}$. And what we want is $\Pr(A\cap B)$.  We get
$$\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(B|A)\Pr(A)=\frac{4}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{2}.$$

As to your question about two *consecutive* picks versus two *simultaneous* picks, there is no effective difference. If Alicia picks two balls from the urn, what difference can it make whether she touches the two balls simultaneously, or with a delay of a millisecond?

**Remark:** For this kind of problem, using the formal conditional probability machinery is overkill, and may hinder the intuition.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. Now, if the first ball **isn't** replaced before drawing the second, then $P(B|A)=\frac49$, from which $$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A)=\frac12\cdot\frac49=\frac29.$$ If we *are* replacing the first ball, $P(B|A)=P(B)=\frac12$, and that changes things.

As for the second question, let's use combinatorics. There are $5$ black balls, and we want to choose $2;$ $5$ white balls, choose $0$. Total, there are $10$ balls, and we're choosing $2$. Then the probability of choosing $2$ black balls simultaneously is $$\frac{_5C_2\cdot{}_5C_0}{_{10}C_2}=\frac{10\cdot 1}{45}=\frac29.$$ Thus, we have the same result (if I'm right about not replacing the first ball, anyway).

Comment: +1 Yes, you are right about not replacing the first ball. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If the first ball is not replaced after extraction, both probabilities are the same.

$P(\text{first ball black and second ball black})$

$=P(\text{first ball black}) \cdot P(\text{second ball black } | \text{ first ball black})$

$=\frac{5}{10}\cdot\frac{4}{9}$

$=\frac{2}{9}$

Answer (score 0):

**Why would you even split it into two events?!**

You are just picking two balls. There are `C(10,2)=45` ways to pick two balls out of 10, but only `C(5,2)=10` give you two black ones. So `10/45 = 2/9` is your answer.